# How to get intput stream from .txt file ( android )?

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream

I want to read my data from my .txt file into a ReaderClass in android, fields are seperated by ";"

---- here is my solution of my last post:

```
public void cut()
  {
  try{    


  InputStream input =context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.textfile);
  BufferedReader br = null;
  br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input,"iso-8859-1"));
  String line = null; 


  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)   {        

      String[] decoupage= line.split(";");


      String titre=decoupage[0];
      String description=decoupage[1];
      String reponse=decoupage[2];
      String explication=decoupage[3];
      String categorie=decoupage[4];
      String etat=decoupage[5];       

                    //test Logcat

            Log.d("information ", " buffer");
        Log.i("titre : ",titre);
        Log.i("description : ",description);
        Log.i("reponse : ",reponse);
        Log.i("explication : ",explication);
        Log.i("categorie : ",categorie);
        Log.i("etat : ",etat);



      }
  in.close();

    }catch (Exception e){
  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
  System.err.println("\n File not found");
  }
  //end
  }
```

Comment: Atleast try **something** before you ask questions!

Comment: I have commented at your another question : ** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483992/how-to-find-my-db-file-in-sqlite **  can you answer for that and can help me to increase my knowledge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FileInputStream fis;
fis = openFileInput("sample.txt");
StringBuffer Content = new StringBuffer("");

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    Content.append(new String(buffer));
}

you will get entire content in a string buffer ,convert it into string, then you can apply yourString.split(";") to get all values which you can keep in some array.
```

Comment: Where I mention the separation " ; "between fields ?

Comment: you will get a string buffer convert it into a string then apply <your string variable name>.split(";")

Comment: both will serve same purpose u can use any method ... plz mark it as answer if my post helped you :)

Comment: please go through this link to choose it will be best if you continue with split() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: @Chintan If the file is where you say it is, and your application is com.example.packagename, then calling openFileInput("123.ics"); will return you a FileInputStream on the file in question.
Or, call getFilesDir() to get a File object pointing to /data/data/com.example.packagename/files, and work from there.